# Spring RowMapper NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception

I've tried looking around for an answer to my problem but haven't been able to resolve it.

My application is throwing a NPE in my RowMapper class at line 46:

```
orderLineRepository.sqlGetOrderLinesForOrder(rs.getInt("orderId"))
```

Could somebody please help me out with this? I'm not too sure what's wrong with it.

**Here's a copy of the classes:**

```
@Repository("orderRepository")
public class OrderRepository {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    public Order sqlGetOrderByOrderId(int orderId) {
        String sql = "SELECT om.orderId, om.orderRef, om.orderChannel, "
                + "om.orderCreated, om.orderCompleted, om.orderStatus, "
                + "c.customerId, c.name, c.email, c.phoneNumber, "
                + "a.addressId, a.houseNameNumber, a.streetName, "
                + "a.addressLine2, a.addressLine3, a.addressLine4, "
                + "a.postCode, a.countryCode "
                + "FROM OrderMain om "
                + "INNER JOIN Customer c ON om.customerId=c.customerId "
                + "INNER JOIN Address a ON om.addressId=a.addressId "
                + "WHERE om.orderId=?";

        return jdbc.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {orderId}, new OrderRowMapper());
    }

}
```

***Order row mapper:***

```
public class OrderRowMapper implements RowMapper<Order> {

    @Autowired
    private OrderLineRepository orderLineRepository;

    public Order mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setCustomerId(rs.getInt("customerId"));
        customer.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        customer.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
        customer.setPhoneNumber(rs.getString("phoneNumber"));

        Address address = new Address();
        address.setAddressId(rs.getInt("addressId"));
        address.setHouseNameNumber(rs.getString("houseNameNumber"));
        address.setStreetName(rs.getString("streetName"));
        address.setAddressLine2(rs.getString("addressLine2"));
        address.setAddressLine3(rs.getString("addressLine3"));
        address.setAddressLine4(rs.getString("addressLine4"));
        address.setPostcode(rs.getString("postcode"));
        address.setCountryCode(rs.getString("countryCode"));

        Order order = new Order(
                    rs.getInt("orderId"),
                    rs.getString("orderRef"),
                    rs.getString("orderChannel"),
                    rs.getTimestamp("orderCreated"),
                    rs.getTimestamp("orderCompleted"),
                    OrderStatus.orderStatusGetById(rs.getInt("orderStatus")),
                    customer,
                    address,
                    orderLineRepository.sqlGetOrderLinesForOrder(rs.getInt("orderId"))
                );

        return order;
    }

}
```

**This is calling my orderLineRepository, below:**

```
@Repository("orderLineRepository")
public class OrderLineRepository {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedJdbc;

    public List<OrderLine> sqlGetOrderLinesForOrder(int orderId) {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("orderId", orderId);

        String sql = "SELECT itemId, orderQty, cancelledQty, "
                + "despatchedQty, replacedQty, refundedQty, "
                + "orderLineStatus, orderValue, unitValue, "
                + "shippingCost "
                + "FROM OrderLine "
                + "WHERE orderId=:orderId";

        return namedJdbc.query(sql, params, new OrderLineRowMapper());
    }

    public List<OrderLine> sqlGetAllOrderLines() {
        String sql = "SELECT itemId, orderQty, cancelledQty, "
                + "despatchedQty, replacedQty, refundedQty, "
                + "orderLineStatus, orderValue, unitValue, "
                + "shippingCost "
                + "FROM OrderLine";

        return jdbc.query(sql, new OrderLineRowMapper());
    }

}
```

**If required, here is my OrderLineRowMapper:**

```
public class OrderLineRowMapper implements RowMapper<OrderLine> {

    public OrderLine mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        OrderLine orderLine = new OrderLine();
             orderLine.setItemId(rs.getInt("itemId"));
             orderLine.setOrderQty(rs.getInt("orderQty"));
             orderLine.setCancelledQty(rs.getInt("cancelledQty"));
             orderLine.setDespatchedQty(rs.getInt("despatchedQty"));
             orderLine.setReplacedQty(rs.getInt("replacedQty"));
             orderLine.setRefundedQty(rs.getInt("refundedQty"));
             orderLine.setOrderLineStatus(OrderLineStatus.orderLineStatusGetById(rs.getInt("orderLineStatus")));
             orderLine.setOrderValue(rs.getDouble("orderValue"));
             orderLine.setUnitValue(rs.getDouble("unitValue"));
             orderLine.setShippingCost(rs.getDouble("shippingCost"));
        return orderLine;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you expect Spring to autowire anything when you are creating the object yourself?

```
return namedJdbc.query(sql, params, new OrderLineRowMapper());
```

Spring can only inject beans into other Spring managed beans.

Have Spring create a `OrderLineRowMapper` bean and inject and use it in your `OrderLineRepository` class.

Comment: If this is the case, why does it return the correct results when I create a service that calls my OrderLineRepository directly, rather than through my OrderRowMapper?

Comment: @user I made a mistake, confused `OrderRowMapper` with `OrderLineRowMapper`. How and where are you using `OrderRowMapper`?

Comment: OrderRowMapper is being used in my OrderRepository, I'll update my post.

Comment: @user So you are doing the same thing in `OrderRepository`, ie. creating a `new OrderRowMapper()` instead of getting a managed bean from Spring. The `orderLineRepository` field is going to stay `null`.

Comment: Thanks so much @Sotirios-delimanolis! It's working now that OrderRowMapper has been created as a bean. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @user You're welcome. Any time you have a `null` with Spring, it's probably because something isn't being managed correctly. Spring will throw a bunch of exceptions of its own if it cannot autowire something. Also, consider accepting the answer unless there's something missing.